# How to use multiple source_type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

My models are below at present.

**`user.rb`**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authentications
end
```

**`authentication.rb`**

```
class Authentication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :social, polymorphic: true 
end
```

**`facebook.rb`**

```
class Facebook < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :authentication, as: :social
end
```

**`twitter.rb`**

```
class Twitter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :authentication, as: :social
end
```

Now thanks to polymorphic association, I can access either **`Twitter` or `Facebook`** objects from an `Authentication` object as follows:

```
 authentication.social
```

Then I want to access the `Twitter` or `Facebook` object directly from a `User` object as well using the **`:through`** option to call single method like below:

```
user.socials
```

So I tried modifying the `User` model like the following two samples:

**sample1**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authentications
  has_many :socials, through: :authentications, source: :social, source_type: "Twitter"
  has_many :socials, through: :authentications, source: :social, source_type: "Facebook"
end
```

**sample2**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authentications
  has_many :socials, through: :authentications, source: :social, source_type: ["Twitter", "Facebook"]
end
```

But neither approach worked.

How can I access those objects with a single method like `user.socials`?

I heard **`:source`** and **`:source_type`** are for using polymorphic association on **`:through`**.
If we have to use separate methods like **`user.twitters`** and **`user.facebooks`** instead of **`user.socials`**, I think those options are contradictory to their original concept.

Thanks in advance.

:edit

I'm using

```
ruby 2.1.2p95
Rails 4.2.0.beta2
```

Comment: Please check https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3882
The fix is merged in [Rails 4.2.0.beta2](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/828134b7561bf4473580d76bd8d7ae97e9b1db92)
You can upgrade to latest version when stable version releases, till then you can use the [workaround](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3882#issuecomment-4155383)

Comment: Thanks! @Allerin . But my question is different from the issue you suggest. my question is that, as I wrote above, can I access polymorphic models by single method when using "through" option.
And also, I'm already using 4.2.0.beta2.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 7):

This is a old question, but I believe it will help someone.

I didn't found a great solution, but I've reached a simple solution that may be a slow one.

You have to know all possibles entities associated to your (in your case) Authentication model. Then your User model should have a method named `socials`. You should have something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authentications
  has_many :twitters, through: :authentications, source: :social, source_type: "Twitter"
  has_many :facebooks, through: :authentications, source: :social, source_type: "Facebook"

 def socials
  twitters + facebooks
 end
end
```

Hope it helps someone! :D

Comment: Wow! Many thanks for this. I thought I could used `.zip` but I was getting an array instead.